# Conditional independence and joint distributions in graphical models

Tags: probability, independence, joint-distribution, conditional-independence

I'm reading [Deep Learning](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/prob.html) by Ian Goodfellow and Yoshua Bengio and Aaron Courville. 
In chapter 3 about graphical models, to reduce the model complexity, we assume that certain conditional independence assumptions hold. Specifically, in equation 3.52 on page 75 (I quote)

> ... suppose we have three random variables: $a$, $b$ and $c$. Suppose that $a$ inﬂuences
>   the value of $b$, and $b$ inﬂuences the value of $c$ , but
>   that $a$ and $c$ are independent given $b$. We can represent the probability
>   distribution over all three variables as a product of probability
>   distributions over two variables:
>
> $p(a,b,c) = p(a)p(b|a)p(c|b)$

I understand the last statement "$a$ and $c$ are independent given $b$" as conditional independence, and I would write it down as,

$p(a,c|b) = p(a|b)p(c|b)$

Is this right ?
How should I prove the claim mentioned in the book ? I tried to use my result (of conditional independence) with the chain rule or product rule of conditional probabilities, but I could not arrive the claim (3.52 on page 75) mentioned in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right about $(,|)=(|)(|)$, it is the definition of *conditional independence*. For the formula, without any information about the variables/events, we normally have the following, holding always:
$$p(a,b,c)=\underbrace{p(a)p(b|a)}_{p(a,b)}p(c|a,b)$$

When, $c$ and $a$ are independent given $b$, we also have $p(c|a,b)=p(c|b)$ as in the formula. This is very intuitive because $b$ is given, and having $a$ additionally doesn't influence the distribution of $c$, since they're defined as conditionally independent.

We can also deduce this relationship using your formula:
$$p(c|a,b)=\frac{p(a,b,c)}{p(a,b)}=\frac{p(a,c|b)p(b)}{p(a|b)p(b)}=\frac{p(a|b)p(c|b)}{p(a|b)}=p(c|b)$$